# execute the async task in serial order in android4.0

Tags: android, concurrency, android-asynctask

I have implemented the 2 asyn tasks, I am using android4.0. where one asyntask is executed continuously, second one is executed based on requirement(may be mulitpe times).
For example.

```
class AsynTask1 exetends AsyncTask<Void, Bitmap, Void>{
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        while(true){
            publishProgress(bmp);
        }
    }
}

class AsynTask2 extends AsyncTask<String, Void,Void>{
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params){
        System.out.println(params[0])
    }
}
```

In activity class

```
class MainActivity extends Activity{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new AsynTask1().execute();

        int i=0;
        while(i<100)
        {
            if(i%2==0)
            new AsynTask2().execute("no is even"+i);
            i++
        }
    }
}
```

In the above case the AsynTask2 is not executed .

If tried with executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_Executor,params), then both asyntask are executed and I am getting the print messages from the AsynTask2, but those are not in order(like 0 2 6 4 10 8 12 14 ....).

Is there any way to execute the AsynTask1 continuously and AsynTask2 in Sequential order so that the order(like 0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14....) is prevented.

Thanks & Regards
mini.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [SERIAL_EXECUTOR](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#SERIAL_EXECUTOR) for Asynctask2

```
 new AsynTask2().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR ,"no is even"+i)
```

Edit:
Use for  Asynctask1 , so that same executor is not used

```
 new AsynTask1().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_Executor,params);
```

Comment: I tried with this, but the AsyncTask2 is not executed so that I am not getting the messages from the AsynTask2.  is ThreadPool is same for all asyntasks?

Comment: did you do this only for Asynctask2 or even for asynctask1?

Comment: I tried this for both AsynTasks, later I tried for only AsynTask2.

Comment: ok.. i edited my answer. Turns out normal execute uses Serial executor, so put the Aynctask1 on threadpool executor

Comment: Thank you for your response, I tried with this also but AsynTask2 is not executed.

Comment: oops. Looks like even serial_executor inturn uses the threadpoolexecutor. You will have to create a new Executor. You can use SerailExecutor from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) and then pass it to one of them. Both asynctasks need to be on different executors and Asynctask2 should be on serial Executor

Comment: If u know the implementation Customized Serial Executor, Please share.

Comment: its at the link i [shared](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html). Search for SerialExecutor

Comment: I used the SerialEXecutor class given in above link.                 In Activity class I am calling it new while(i<100){ if(i%==0){                                 AsynTAsk2.executeOnExecutor(new SerialExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)),i) ;               }i++;}    but I am getting the messages from asyntask2 is like 0 2 6 4 10 8 12 14 ....). not in 0 2 4 6 8 12 14 .....

Answer (score 0):

Try using call backs. Define the interfaces in your AsyncTask classes and implement them in the main class. Use the callBack on onPostExecute of AsyncTask2 to launch the next AsyncTask2. You'll guarantee the order.

```
 class AsyncTask2 extends AsyncTask<String, Void,Boolean<{
        //Your code. doInBackground must now return a boolean.
        protected Void onPostExecute(final Boolean success){
            myCallback listener = (myCallback) parentActivity;
            listener.call();
        }

        public Interface myCallback{
            void call();
        }
 }
```

And then on your main activity you implement myCallback.

[EDIT]

Here's a sample of what you could do.

```
Class MainActivity extends Activity implements myCallback{
    //Your code
    public void call(){
       new AsyncTask2().execute("no is even" + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I don't know about the callbacks and their implementation.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are not supposed to use AsyncTask for long-running threads (the way you are implementing AsyncTask1). See the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html . Just create a separate thread for what AsyncTask1 is doing.
2. Since you need serial execution for what you are doing in AsyncTask2 can be done by creating a ThreadPool of size 1.

   ```
   // Creating ThreadPool
   ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

   // Submitting task
   service.execute(task);

   // Shutting down the thread pool when not required.
   service.shutdown();
   ```

Answer (score -2):

```
    int i=0;
    while(i<100)
    {
      new AsynTask1().execute();
        if(i%2==0)
      {
        new AsynTask2().execute("no is even"+i);
       }
        i++
    }
```

Comment: If I use the above one, then AsynTask1 is called for every iteration , I don't want to call AsynTask1 per every iteration.