# Multiple Async Task not running in android 4.1

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my android app i'm using 3 different async task.
2 tasks are running in Activity A and 3rd one is in Activity B. While i'm running the app in Emulator of OS version 2.3 application is working fine. But while i'm trying in Android 4.0 or higher version only first Asynctask is running.

Is there any way to run all the 3 Async tasks in 4.0 and higher version?

Comment: please post your code with your logcat snippet.

Answer (score 5):

You can do the following:

YourAsyncTaskClassObjectName.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);

instead of the normal execute:

YourAsyncTaskClassObjectName.execute()

This actually worked for my simple non business app. Now, I've the doInBackground methods of two asynctasks running forever (i've while(true) inside each).

Caveat: I'm not saying this is the best design but this actually worked.

Answer (score 4):

With Android 4.0, AsyncTask have ben granted only one background thread of execution i.e. only one will run at a time. This was the same behaviour in FroYo, but was lifted in Gingerbread. hence then you could run multiple AsyncTasks. So the best way to proceed is to serialize your AsyncTasks. Parallelizing will lead to unpredicatable results.

Comment: Afaik `AsyncTaskLoader` and the rest of `Loaders` implement `AsyncTask` for the background work. Do you know if it handles parallel tasks? I think it does, but would like to hear it from someone

Answer (score 1):

Hi you have to write your own executors. Please follow the post

[execute the async task in serial order in android4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105730/execute-the-async-task-in-serial-order-in-android4-0)

Comment: i used AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_Executor, its working fine. but its minimum API level is 11. i need to run on API level 8 also. Is der any equalent code for that?

Answer (score 0):

It's the correct behavior. AsyncTask since Android 4.0 , performes consistently.