# Running multiple background tasks in Android 4.0

Tags: android

How do I do multiple background tasks in Android?

For example downloading and at the same time uploading files?

What is the best way to do this? I referred to [execute the async task in serial order in android4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105730/execute-the-async-task-in-serial-order-in-android4-0)

But I can only get the downloading to work, the uploading portion nothing happens? I have tried using two different async tasks but still the same issue, only downloading works.

Is there any other way to implement this?

Comment: You've had multiple answers, it would be appreciated if you responded.

Answer (score 1):

Since Honeycomb asynchronous tasks are executed one after the other. If you really want parallel execution of two (or more) AsyncTasks you have to start the tasks with the method "executeOnExecutor" (instead of "execute") using AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR as the executor.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own Threads for this type of work. Since IntentService has its own queue same as AsyncTask you cannot run multiple background tasks at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is potentially that since Honeycomb, AsyncTask uses a serial thread single thread sequence.

For downloading or uploading anything more than a thumbnail, you should be using a service, IntentService is probably easiest to start off with although getting that simultaneously working will require you to spawn off a worker thread (which you should do anyway).

Vogella has a good overview.
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html